# Complex integral and residue theorem: Poles at path

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x sin(\pi x) dx/(1-x^2)$$

I know i am doing something wrong, since i am getting 0 as answer:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x sin(\pi x) dx/(1-x^2) = I$$

$$I + (-\pi i)Res(x sin(\pi x)/(1-x^2),-1) + (-\pi i)Res(x sin(\pi x)/(1-x^2),+1) = 0$$

Where i am following this path:

[image]

Since $sin(\pi x)$ at $x = \pm 1* is zero, our sum reduce to $$I + 0 + 0 = 0$$.

I have no idea where is the error,

Comment: There are several mistakes. First, you should write $\sin t=\Im e^{i\pi t}$ and take the imaginary part of the integral with $e^{i\pi t}$ - if you want to close the contour in the upper half-plane. Second, the integral is supposed to be evaluated in the principal value sence. It means that you added two small half-circles to get a closed contour, and integration along these half-circles has to be deducted from the integral along the closed contour (and the integral along  the closed contour is zero in fact, because there no poles inside).

Comment: Without complex integration $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin(\pi x) dx}{1-x^2}=-\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{i\pi x}}{(x-1)(x+1)}dx=-\frac{1}{2}{\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}}e^{i\pi x}\Big(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-1}\Big)dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\Im\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi (t-1)}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi (t+1)}\frac{dt}{t}\Big)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \pi t}{t}dt=\pi$$